# Is there a list of all android values folder?

Tags: android, android-resources

I need to know which device uses which values folder. I couldn't find any code like this. I just wanted to do this.

```
public String getValuesFolder(){
    
    ....

    return "values-sw600dp";//after this method finished, it would give me correctly unique values-folder

}
```

But after some searching, there is no method like this. So I just decided to create all values folder in the test project. Every values folder has a string.xml that contains its name, for example

```
in values-v19

 ->string.xml

 <string name="folder_name">v19</string>
```

In this way, If I have all values folder in this test project, I would learn easily which values folder be in use?

But I couldn't find any full list. Is there any list like that?

Comment: "I need to know which device uses which values folder" -- a single device could use any number of "values folders". A given resource set provides *candidate* resources. Which resources get used are based on the resource being requested and what candidates there are across all resource sets. "But after some searching, there is no method like this" -- that is because it is not possible. "So I just decided to create all values folder in the test project" -- there is an infinite number of possible resource sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of following values to figure out the values being used based on the device the app is running.

```
private void getDisplayDensity() {
// this will return you the density of the screen - hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi/xxxhdpi...etc
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

if (density >= 4.0) {
    //xxxhdpi    
} else if (density >= 3.0) {
    //xxhdpi   
} else if (density >= 2.0) {
    //xhdpi  
} else if (density >= 1.5) {
    //hdpi  
} else if (density >= 1.0) {
    //mdpi
} else {
    //ldpi  
}
}

public double getDeviceScreenSize(Activity activity) {
   //this will return you screen size of the device like 5.5 or 7 inches etc.
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
    return Math.sqrt(x + y);
}
```

If you have folders like values-sw600dp that will used if density of the device is xhdpi and screen size is more that 7 inches. similarly, you can figure out this based screen size and density matrix as shown in the images below to create a generic logic for the same.

[image: screen_density_vs_screensize]
[image: relation_pic]

Comment: More info here - https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes